# How to Remove Phonegap Build Config File GPS Permission

Tags: cordova, gps, android-manifest, phonegap-build

I used the following config for a phonegap build. But after build it asks for android.hardware.location.gps  How can I make it not require this capability on the config file. I need to remove it to make it compatible for amazon. Please help.

```
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
  <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
  <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>



  <feature name="permissions" value="none"/>


  <!-- Core plugins -->
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"/>

  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
  <access origin="*"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: Ensure that you dont have any additional plugins included in your plugins folder and platform json files

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about amazon but I assume that you are building an android application.

I can suggest you 2 options. 
First, make a modification to 'AndroidManifest.xml' which is located in
platforms/android. 
When you open the file, you'll see

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

These are the permissions for GPS. 
Make sure that you don't disable

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

because phonegap requires a network connection.

Second option is to use a plugin called, 'custom-config'.

Please see [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config)